# Spry Tabbed Panel Widget

Tags: dreamweaver, spry, panels, tabbed

Hopefully someone can help. I have a working Spry tabbed panel widget in my site structured as standard with the following main tabs:

```
<ul class="TabbedPanelsTabGroup">
   <li class="TabbedPanelsTab tabindex="0"></li>
   <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0"></li>
   <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0"></li>
   <li class="TabbedPanelsTab" tabindex="0"></li> 
</ul>
```

It all works totally fine and opens the relevant content areas etc. However, I wish to alter the behaviour of the tabbed panel....

what I would like (for reasons too complicated to go into!) is for one of the above tabs to not actually open a content area but instead to just link out to another website in another window. I cant seem to get the JavaScript to only apply to some of the tabs.

In summary I would like 3 of the tabs to behave as normal, and open the relevant content areas (this is currently working)

And one of the tabs to just function like a normal link to any other href.

Pleeeeease Help!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the tab that you want to be a link
2. Add `onFocus` in the Behaviors panel with a go to URL event so that when it's clicked, it redirects you to your link or opens a new window
3. In the content pane, you could simply add a comment for the reader that shows the page is open in another window